# Recover expired bonus points for accepted answer

Tags: support, bounties

On some of the bounty questions, my answer has been accepted after the bounty expired. It most recently happened here: [Many to Many Relationships without Double Junction Tables, Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772249/many-to-many-relationships-without-double-junction-tables-entity-framework)

Is there anyway to get these points or are they just lost?

Comment: Just out of interest, how much was the bounty for?

Comment: @Andy, this one was 300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are gone forever.  Bounties are auto-awarded on the highest voted answer that has at least 2 up votes and, since your answer didn't (and still doesn't) have 2 at the time the bounty expired, those rep points were cast into the void.

FYI, answer accepting and bounty awarding are no longer linked.  Accepting an answer doesn't automatically award them the bounty and, likewise, answers are no longer auto-accepted when the bounty period is over.  The fact that your answer was accepted doesn't imply that the OP wanted to award the bounty to you, however likely it may be.

Comment: almost, but there was a recent tweak to allow accepts (DURING the bounty period only) to confer bounties at the end of the bounty period if no other signals are provided.